# Proper use of Q_OBJECT?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

If I derive my class from `QObject` (or a subclass), the Qt documentation says that I have to put the  `Q_OBJECT` macro into my class declaration.

It also says I need to "run the meta-object compiler" for my class.

I have no idea how to do this. Is this something I need to add to the .pro file?  Do I need to edit the makefile?  This seems overly complicated for a simple derived class.

I'm using Qt Creator.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the help.  I discovered something very important:  When I create a new class in Qt Creator, I have to specify "Inherits QWidget" as the type information, even if I'm already specifying a Qt widget as my base class (such as `QTextEdit`). It seems strange that Qt Creator couldn't figure that out on its own, but that seems to solve my signal/slot and moc problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt uses the `moc` compiler to produce its meta-object system (which is required for introspecting classes and allowing for signals/slots, amongst other things).

By default, `qmake` will do the right thing when generating and compiling the `moc_*.cpp` files.

Answer (score 2):

If your classes going to **use signals and slots**, use the macro `Q_OBJECT`. Else it is not necessary. If there is no signals and slots, just go on with your normal c++ way of using classes and all should work fine. You will not specifically go on and create moc_*.cpp files, but as "theatrus" said qmake will do that stuff for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: All QObject subclasses should always have Q_OBJECT. Otherwise stuff like the metaobject features won't work correctly.

Comment: @ Frank, oh is it?? Thanks... What are the all the metaobject features you were referring too?? I haven't tried any of those before

Answer (score 1):

The `Q_OBJECT` simply needs to be put in your class declaration, like this:

```
class MyObject : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

   // etc.
};
```